# Jersey 2.1 - Consuming collection of POJO as JSON string

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, jersey-2.0

I have a collection of entities (List) which I need to convert to/from json.

The POJO:

```
public class Task {

    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private Boolean done;
    (...)
}
```

Jersey produces the following result

```
[{"id":1,"title":"T1","done":false},{"id":2,"title":"T2","done":false}]
```

when I call the method:

```
@GET
@Override
@Produces("application/json")
public List<Task> findAll() {
    (...)
    return tasks;
}
```

So far so good.

Now, I need to consume a similar JSON string. I assumed that the following method would do the trick:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public void save(List<Task> tasks) {
    (...)
}
```

But instead I get the error below:

```
    SEVERE:   line 1:0 no viable alternative at input
'"[{\"id\":1,\"title\":\"T1\",\"done\":true},{\"id\":2,\"title\":\"T2\",\"done\":false}]"'
```

What am I doing wrong? Is that even possible?

Jersey's dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Here is the web.xml configuration

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my.rest.package</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: How do you map a `Task` to JSON? Do you use JAXB?

Comment: I added the moxy module to my pom.xml as described [here](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json.moxy). The json serialization is fine, the problem is the deserialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you're sending corrupted JSON as entity in your message body, something like:

```
POST http://localhost:9998/test/list
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
"[{\"a\":\"a\",\"b\":1,\"c\":1}]"
```

I was able to get the same error as you with the entity like this (`line 1:0 no viable alternative at input '"[{\"a\":\"a\",\"b\":1,\"c\":1}]"'`).

Make sure you're sending the valid JSON to your REST service, i.e. by registering a logging filter in your Application:

```
new ResourceConfig()
    .packages("my.rest.package")
    // Register logging filter and print entity.
    .register(new LoggingFilter(LOGGER, true));
```

Comment: You nailed that one! The exception was caused by an invalid JSON massage. I was calling JSON.stringify() twice. My bad!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can accept the incoming JSON as String and parse it within the method using any standard parser.

```
@PUT
public void save(String s) {
   // parse s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Type parameters are not available after [type erasure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure).

Try using array instead of list:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
public void save(Task[] taskArray) {
    List<Task> tasks = Arrays.asList(taskArray);
    (...)
}
```